# Inactive caption text color in Windows 10

Tags: windows, winapi

In Windows 10, how do you get the color of inactive caption text?

In the example below, "Untitled - Notepad" is gray when window is inactive:

[image: Notepad active and inactive window]

But the color I get is black when I try the following functions:

```
color = GetSysColor(COLOR_INACTIVECAPTIONTEXT);
//color = black, wrong

HTHEME htheme = OpenThemeData(hwnd, L"WINDOW");
color = GetThemeSysColor(htheme, COLOR_INACTIVECAPTIONTEXT);
//color = black, wrong

GetThemeColor(htheme, WP_CAPTION, CS_INACTIVE, TMT_TEXTCOLOR, &color);
//color = black, wrong
```

`DrawThemeText` and `DrawThemeTextEx` also print the inactive caption in black.

All of these functions work fine in Windows 7 because inactive caption remains the same color, only the Aero glass thing changes color. But it's not the same in Windows 10.

Comment: If Windows says the color is black, then then color is black. Maybe Windows 10 is drawing inactive text differently than earlier versions did.

Comment: Maybe I am using the wrong flags or something?

Comment: No.  A color is just a color, but you don't always know how the color will be used.

Comment: I have the same issue...  I need to find the brush to draw windowchrome content but the SystemColor brushes are Black but clearly the title and min/max/close buttons use something else (light-gray)

Comment: Could it be black, but translucent?